# Handle multiple requests in Guzzle between two Laravel projects at same time

Tags: php, laravel, apache, lumen, guzzle

I'm working in two projects, a Laravel 8 project and a Laravel Lumen 8 project, both of which use Guzzle to make HTTP requests, they're running on the following domains:

- **Laravel 8** http://localhost:8000
- **Laravel Lumen 8** http://localhost:8001

And I'm using MAMP Pro (Apache and MySQL).

My Laravel 8 project makes a HTTP request to my Lumen project, which makes a HTTP request back to my Laravel 8 project, the problem I'm facing is that the first request from my Laravel project always times out and then the request starts from the Lumen project.

This isn't what I want, I need the first request to instantly start the request in my Lumen project and have it return a response back to the very first request.

What am I missing from my HTTP request structure to allow this to happen? I've tried utilising sessions in the db as I thought it might be session blocking or queuing the requests:

**Laravel 8 project's request (first)**

```php
/**
   * Route the microservice
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  public function microservice(Request $request, $service)
  {
      Log::debug("HUB Microservice");

      // TODO: this is always timing out regardless of what timeout I set
      // seems to only start the Lumen request when this finishes but I need
      // the response from the Lumen's request to be here
      $response = Http::timeout(20)->get('http://localhost:8001/api/reports');

      // the response from the microservice on the Lumen project
      return response()->json($response->json(), $response->status());
  }
```

**Laravel Lumen 8 project's request (second, needs to return the response back to the first)**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class BeforeMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability)
    {
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000',
            'timeout' => 60
        ]);

        // TODO: this request only ever starts when my Laravel (first) request
        // times out, is it domain related?
        $res = $client->request('POST', '/api/hub/login', [
            'form_params' => [
                'key' => 'value'
            ]
        ]);

        // Post-Middleware Action
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

What am I missing

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laragon (nginx) for local development.

I fixed it by raising Upstream from 2 to 5.

It can be increased in this file: `C:\laragon\usr\laragon.ini`

[laragon.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUKib.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your server configuration. On windows php-cgi cant handle several connections simultaneously. So before start second script, php-cgi.exe waits until first is end.

You can use build-in php server (`php -S`) which allows you to handle connections to `8000` and `8001` separately